# How can I change the length, thickness and curvature of a simple oblong/line in the browser?

Tags: css, animation, svg, graphics, gsap

I've been working in the backend for the past six months, and it's years since I did graphic manipulation on the front, so I'm looking for guidance on this issue as I'm not even sure in which direction to head.  I've done an hour of googling but I'm finding that none of the things that come up is what I'm looking for -- and it dawned on me that I'm not even sure *what* I'm looking for exactly.

Our clients want to have a page where a simple oblong image is modified by three sliders, each of which represents length, width and 'bend', (see attached images).

I am not sure how to do this -- my mind says 'SVG', although I haven't worked with SVG in the past.  Can I modify an existing SVG image using CSS?  Would the `MorphSVGPlugin` (https://greensock.com/docs/v2/Plugins/MorphSVGPlugin) from Greensock be my best bet?  I've worked with Greensock in the past, but I don't now if it's overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any clues!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe an idea to start with:https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206001/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the L command for line I'm using the Q command for quadratic Bézier.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
let angle = 2.5;// line's angle
let R,//line's length/2
r;//line's curvature. In the begining r=0 (no curvature)



R = ~~strokeLength.value/2;
r = ~~itr.value;
thePath.style.strokeWidth = strokeWidth.value
thePath.setAttribute("d",getD(R,r));

//set the stroke's width
strokeWidth.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  thePath.style.strokeWidth = strokeWidth.value
})
//set the stroke's length
strokeLength.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 R = ~~strokeLength.value/2;
 thePath.setAttribute("d",getD(R,r))
})
//set the stroke's curvature
itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 r = ~~itr.value;
 thePath.setAttribute("d",getD(R,r))
})

//a function to calculate the new d attribute
function getD(R,r){
  let p1 = {//move to this point
    x:R*Math.cos(angle),
    y:R*Math.sin(angle)
  }
  
  let p2 = {//end the curve in this point
    x:R*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI),
    y:R*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI)
  }
  
  let pc = {//calculate the control point for the bézier
    x:r*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2),
    y:r*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2)
  }
  
  let d = `M${p1.x},${p1.y}Q${pc.x},${pc.y} ${p2.x},${p2.y}`;
  return d;
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid; float:left; margin:10px}
span{display:inline-block; width:130px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" width="200">
  <path id="thePath" d="M-80,80L80,-80" stroke="skyBlue" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" />
</svg>
<p><span>stroke's width</span><input id="strokeWidth" type="range" min="1" max="30" value="10"/></p>
<p><span>stroke's length</span><input id="strokeLength" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="50"/></p>
<p><span>stroke's curvature</span><input id="itr" type="range" min="-200" max="200" value="0"/></p>
```